# How to define (using Zod) an object that, depending on the key pattern, expects different value types?

Tags: typescript, zod

Here is the type I am trying to redefine using Zod:

```
type MyType = {
  [_: `@{string}`]: number[];
  [_: string]: string;
};
```

This should be successfully parsed at the end:

```
const data: MyType = {
 "@p1": [1, 2, 3],
 "otherKey": "aValue"
}
```

I tried to do the union of 2 records:

1. record(z.custom<`@${string}`>((val: any) => /^@/.test(val)), z.array(z.number()))
2. record(z.string(), z.string())

but it is not matching my expectations because it does not allow to mix both key patterns.

What I am looking is something similar to this:

```
z.object({
  [z.custom<`@${string}`>((val: any) => /^@/.test(val))]: z.array(z.number()),
  [z.string()]: z.string(),
})
```

Anyone knows how to do that?

Thanks! :)